# Changing Jquery to AJAX url GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

First of all I want to apologize for the title couldn't find a better title.

I am new to ajax and I want to change my jquery to ajax. I wanted to do it in the same jquery but the jquery I am using already have a `url` and I dont think you can use two `url` at the same time.

**My current jquery** *this works and if  you understand this, you should be able to understand what I want to*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selected').hide();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var length = $('#length').val();
        var Category = $('#Category').val();
        var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var price = '\u00A3' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * qty;
        var category = $('#Category').text();
        var length = $('#length').val();
        if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Quantity should not be below 1 or null');
            return false; // don't continue
        }
        else {
        $('#sprice').text(price);
        $('#scategory').text(category);
        $('#slength').text(length);
        $('#selected').slideDown();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { pid:pid, 
            length:length, 
            Qty:Qty, 
            Category:Category },
            success: function(data)
            {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

If you notice I needed to hide my `div` called `selected`. This isn't the right way to do it.

**My selected div**

```
         <div class="slidingDiv" id='selected'>
    <table class="tableclass">
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td id='sprice'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category:</td>
            <td id='scategory'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Length:</td>
            <td id='slength'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**I try this ajax code i found on w3school**

```
function showitem(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("showtxt").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("showtxt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","showitem.php?pid="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

but it doesn't work because I am inexperience with it.

**Want I want to do**

I don't want to hide the `selected` because if you disable javascript it shows.

What I intend to do it. if that when you click the add button `onclick` using the ajax, it will send the length, pid, category and Qty to `showitem.php` and in this showitem.php it will calculate multiply price * Qty and then echo out into

```
<table class="tableclass">
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td id='sprice'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category:</td>
            <td id='scategory'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Length:</td>
            <td id='slength'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**showitem.php**

```
<?php
include('global.php');
    dbconnect();
$id=$_POST["pid"];
$Category=$_POST["Category"];
$length=$_POST["length"];
$qty=$_POST["Qty"];
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("
SELECT Product.Name as ProductName, Category.Name, Category.CatID, Length, Price
FROM Itemised_Product, Product, Category
WHERE Itemised_Product.ppid =:item_id
AND Hair_Length = :length  AND Category.Name = :Category Limit  1");
$stmt2->bindParam('id',$id);
$stmt2->bindParam('length',$length);  
$stmt2->bindParam('Category',$length);  
$stmt2->bindParam('length',$length);  
$stmt2->execute();
$price = $row["Price"];
foreach ($_SESSION["item_price"]as $each_item) {
$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['Qty'];
$i = 0;
$rows2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
            if ($i == 0) {  
        echo '<table class="tableclass">
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td id='sprice'>' . $totalprice . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category:</td>
            <td id='scategory'>' . $Category . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Length:</td>
            <td id='slength'>'.$length.'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
            }
        }
        }
?>
```

Please help me. if you dont understand the question please leave a comment and i will try and explain it in more details

Comment: "The AJAX Code I found on W3Schools" sounds very fishy :) Generally it's not a good resource. Maybe you should consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1348195

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery to handle all the completed Ajax stuff for you , this is sample  Jquery Ajax code

```
var price = $('#sprice').html();
var length = $('#scategory').html();
var category = $('#slength').html();
$.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data
            url: "showitem.php",

            //GET method is used
            type: "GET",

            //pass the data
            data: '&price='+price+'&category'+category+'&length='+length,
            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,

             beforeSend: function(){
            //do something before data is sent  

            },
             complete: function(html){
             //do soemthing after data has been sent
             },


            //success
            success: function (html) {
            //do something with the result
            },

            error : function ()
            {
            //something went wrong
            }


        });
```

Comment: @MadraDavide 2 qustions. 1) what happened to the div? remember i dont want to hide it. 2) what will be in `form_server.php`?

Comment: @SarahJames  have edited the code ,form_server.php should be showitem.php

Comment: I have edit my code to show what I have done for `showitem.php` please take a look